# Site cannot be access using url/sitename but could access with localhost:port

Tags: sharepoint-server

I create another site on my Sharepoint 2016 server.
The site #1 is using port 80.

I create another site on port 90 with different aplication pool.
but, when i try to access the site using sitename (http://sitename/) it get error "Can`t reach this page".

but when i use localhost:90, it run perfectly.

is there a step that i miss or something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you’re missing a step.  If your web application is listening on port 90, then you’ll need to include that in the URL, such as http://sitename:90/.

You can only leave the port off the URL if you’re using 80 (http) or 443 (https).